# Async cancellabel task

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to implement a behaviour for my application that at the start checks a webservivce if any news are available. If there are news available, pop open a screen to show to the user. If there are no news available, or the user quits the application (or starts the game) i dont want to bother the user but instead cancel the task to retrieve the news item

I thought it would be a breeze doing this with the Task Library but unfortunatly it is not available in the default loadout on Windows Phone (or is it?).

I think the key here is the cancelable part. I certainly know how to start an async op, but what is the best practice for hte cancelable part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Task Parallel Library is available for Windows Phone, in this NuGet package: [System.Threading.Tasks](http://nuget.org/packages/System.Threading.Tasks).

But I don't really get why you care to cancel the task. If the user quits the application, the task end, and if you do another action, nothing happens.

Comment: Thanks for both the link and your view, and you are certainly right, i havent thought of that this way.